# My end screen won't load when i collide with it

Tags: python

So I have started making my end screen and I made it so when it collide's with this one block it will load, every time it collides with this one block my game just freeze it will show the text I wrote but that's all, I wanted it show you the text for a few seconds and make the game restart but it keeps freezing. I have tried punting the code in different places, switching it up/deleting stuff and adding stuff to it, but it still wont work.

https://gyazo.com/b2a5861f14eeba5c43b1e1b6e9894aaa

this is a short clip to show what happens

where I am having my problem

```
black = (0,0,0)
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',25)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    game_loop()
    time.sleep(2)


    
    

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')
```

My full code

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()

#this is screem height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

#know we put screem name
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs first Game")


#player class
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 15
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 7
        self.fall = 5
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft=(self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)
        
 
class item:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)



# Colors
white = (255,255,255)

darkred = (200,0,0)

darkgreen = (0,200,0)

green = (0,255,0)

red = (255,0,0)

#draw player
player1 = player(255,-20,30,30,white)

item1 = item(360,360,30,30,red)
item2 = item(260,360,30,30,red)
item3 = item(100,560,30,30,red)
item4 = item(200,560,30,30,red)
item5 = item(300,760,30,30,red)
item6 = item(400,760,30,30,red)
item7 = item(260,760,30,30,red)
item8 = item(300,960,30,30,red)
item9 = item(200,960,30,30,red)
item10 = item(360,960,30,30,red)
item11 = item(160,1160,30,30,red)
item12 = item(200,1160,30,30,red)
item13 = item(360,1360,30,30,red)
item14 = item(400,1360,30,30,red)
item15 = item(120,1360,30,30,red)
item16 = item(230,1560,30,30,red)
item17 = item(410,1560,30,30,red)
item18 = item(200,1760,30,30,red)
item19 = item(100,1760,30,30,red)
item20 = item(150,1760,30,30,red)
item21 = item(170,1960,30,30,red)
item22 = item(330,1960,30,30,red)
item23 = item(420,1960,30,30,red)
item24 = item(360,2160,30,30,red)
item25 = item(100,2160,30,30,red)
item26 = item(190,2360,30,30,red)
item27 = item(230,2360,30,30,red)
item28 = item(370,2360,30,30,red)
item29 = item(300,2560,30,30,red)
item30 = item(160,2560,30,30,red)
item31 = item(230,2560,30,30,red)
item32 = item(370,2760,30,30,red)
item33 = item(250,2760,30,30,red)
item34 = item(150,2760,30,30,red)
item35 = item(440,2960,30,30,red)
item36 = item(390,2960,30,30,red)
item37 = item(220,3160,30,30,red)
item38 = item(110,3160,30,30,red)
item39 = item(390,3360,30,30,red)
item40 = item(450,3360,30,30,red)
item41 = item(242,3360,30,30,red)
item42 = item(412,3560,30,30,red)
item43 = item(210,3560,30,30,red)
item44 = item(310,3560,30,30,red)
item45 = item(321,3760,30,30,red)
item46 = item(213,3760,30,30,red)
item47 = item(412,3960,30,30,red)
item48 = item(230,3960,30,30,red)
item49 = item(461,3960,30,30,red)
item50 = item(360,4160,30,30,red)
item51 = item(200,4160,30,30,red)
item52 = item(140,4160,30,30,red)
item53 = item(321,4360,30,30,red)
item54 = item(123,4360,30,30,red)
item55 = item(321,4360,30,30,red)
item56 = item(432,4560,30,30,red)
item57 = item(234,4560,30,30,red)
item58 = item(240,4760,30,30,red)
item59 = item(360,4760,30,30,red)
item60 = item(100,4760,30,30,red)
item61 = item(220,4960,30,30,red)
item62 = item(360,4960,30,30,red)
item63 = item(4600,4960,30,30,red)
item64 = item(430,5160,30,30,red)
item65 = item(270,5160,30,30,red)
item66 = item(360,5160,30,30,red)
item67 = item(120,5360,30,30,red)
item68 = item(220,5360,30,30,red)
item69 = item(320,5560,30,30,red)
item70 = item(420,5560,30,30,red)
item71 = item(230,5760,30,30,red)
item72 = item(120,5760,30,30,red)
item73 = item(360,5960,30,30,red)
item74 = item(400,5960,30,30,red)
item75 = item(200,6160,30,30,red)
item76 = item(300,6160,30,30,red)
item77 = item(100,6160,30,30,red)
item78 = item(200,6360,30,30,red)
item79 = item(360,6360,30,30,red)
item80 = item(460,6360,30,30,red)
item81 = item(250,6560,30,30,red)
item82 = item(360,6560,30,30,red)
item83 = item(220,6760,30,30,red)
item84 = item(140,6760,30,30,red)
item85 = item(260,6760,30,30,red)
item86 = item(450,6960,30,30,red)
item87 = item(370,6960,30,30,red)
item88 = item(220,7160,30,30,red)
item89 = item(320,7160,30,30,red)
item90 = item(220,7360,30,30,red)
item91 = item(340,7360,30,30,red)
item92 = item(100,7560,30,30,red)
item93 = item(400,7560,30,30,red)
item94 = item(270,7560,30,30,red)
item95 = item(450,7760,30,30,red)
item96 = item(260,7760,30,30,red)
item97 = item(300,7960,30,30,red)
item98 = item(440,7960,30,30,red)
item99 = item(230,8160,30,30,red)
item100 = item(360,8160,30,30,red)

item101 = item(360,8360,30,30,red)
item102 = item(260,8360,30,30,red)
item103 = item(100,8360,30,30,red)
item104 = item(600,8560,30,30,red)
item105 = item(400,8560,30,30,red)
item106 = item(300,8760,30,30,red)
item107 = item(460,8760,30,30,red)
item108 = item(200,8760,30,30,red)
item109 = item(300,8960,30,30,red)
item110 = item(460,8960,30,30,red)
item111 = item(160,9160,30,30,red)
item112 = item(300,9160,30,30,red)
item113 = item(460,9160,30,30,red)
item114 = item(200,9360,30,30,red)
item115 = item(120,9360,30,30,red)
item116 = item(430,9560,30,30,red)
item117 = item(110,9560,30,30,red)
item118 = item(300,9760,30,30,red)
item119 = item(100,9760,30,30,red)
item120 = item(450,9960,30,30,red)
item121 = item(270,9960,30,30,red)
item122 = item(130,9960,30,30,red)
item123 = item(320,10160,30,30,red)
item124 = item(460,10160,30,30,red)
item125 = item(100,10360,30,30,red)
item126 = item(190,10360,30,30,red)
item127 = item(230,10560,30,30,red)
item128 = item(370,10560,30,30,red)
item129 = item(290,10560,30,30,red)
item130 = item(160,10760,30,30,red)
item131 = item(230,10760,30,30,red)
item132 = item(370,10760,30,30,red)
item133 = item(250,10960,30,30,red)
item134 = item(150,10960,30,30,red)
item135 = item(440,10960,30,30,red)
item136 = item(390,11160,30,30,red)
item137 = item(220,11160,30,30,red)
item138 = item(110,11360,30,30,red)
item139 = item(390,11360,30,30,red)
item140 = item(460,11560,30,30,red)
item141 = item(349,11560,30,30,red)
item142 = item(110,11560,30,30,red)
item143 = item(211,11760,30,30,red)
item144 = item(431,11760,30,30,red)
item145 = item(321,11960,30,30,red)
item146 = item(213,11960,30,30,red)
item147 = item(412,12160,30,30,red)
item148 = item(230,12160,30,30,red)
item149 = item(231,12360,30,30,red)
item150 = item(160,12360,30,30,red)
item151 = item(300,12360,30,30,red)
item152 = item(443,12560,30,30,red)
item153 = item(221,12560,30,30,red)
item154 = item(223,12560,30,30,red)
item155 = item(321,12760,30,30,red)
item156 = item(432,12760,30,30,red)
item157 = item(134,12760,30,30,red)
item158 = item(251,12960,30,30,red)
item159 = item(460,12960,30,30,red)
item160 = item(207,12960,30,30,red)
item161 = item(170,13160,30,30,red)
item162 = item(360,13160,30,30,red)
item163 = item(250,13360,30,30,red)
item164 = item(160,13360,30,30,red)
item165 = item(100,13360,30,30,red)
item166 = item(360,13560,30,30,red)
item167 = item(120,13560,30,30,red)
item168 = item(220,13560,30,30,red)
item169 = item(320,13760,30,30,red)
item170 = item(420,13760,30,30,red)
item171 = item(230,13960,30,30,red)
item172 = item(120,13960,30,30,red)
item173 = item(360,14160,30,30,red)
item174 = item(400,14160,30,30,red)
item175 = item(200,14360,30,30,red)
item176 = item(300,14360,30,30,red)
item177 = item(100,14560,30,30,red)
item178 = item(200,14560,30,30,red)
item179 = item(360,14760,30,30,red)
item180 = item(460,14760,30,30,red)
item181 = item(250,14960,30,30,red)
item182 = item(460,14960,30,30,red)
item183 = item(320,15160,30,30,red)
item184 = item(240,15160,30,30,red)
item185 = item(460,15360,30,30,red)
item186 = item(250,15360,30,30,red)
item187 = item(370,15560,30,30,red)
item188 = item(120,15560,30,30,red)
item189 = item(220,15560,30,30,red)
item190 = item(360,15760,30,30,red)
item191 = item(240,15760,30,30,red)
item192 = item(300,15760,30,30,red)

platform1 = platform(260,400,30,300,red)
platform2 = platform(4,400,30,200,red)
platform3 = platform(4,600,30,440,red)
platform4 = platform(60,800,30,450,red)
platform5 = platform(4,1000,30,60,red)
platform6 = platform(130,1000,30,500,red)
platform7 = platform(4,1200,30,150,red)
platform8 = platform(200,1200,30,400,red)
platform9 = platform(4,1400,30,440,red)
platform10 = platform(4,1600,30,250,red)
platform11 = platform(300,1600,30,300,red)
platform12 = platform(60,1800,30,480,red)
platform13 = platform(4,2000,30,120,red)
platform14 = platform(190,2000,30,400,red)
platform15 = platform(4,2200,30,440,red)
platform16 = platform(70,2400,30,480,red)
platform17 = platform(4,2600,30,440,red)
platform18 = platform(60,2800,30,500,red)
platform19 = platform(4,3000,30,50,red)
platform20 = platform(110,3000,30,400,green)
platform21 = platform(4,3200,30,300,red)
platform22 = platform(360,3200,30,300,red)
platform23 = platform(4,3400,30,320,red)
platform24 = platform(380,3400,30,400,red)
platform25 = platform(4,3600,30,440,red)
platform26 = platform(60,3800,30,500,red)
platform27 = platform(4,4000,30,440,red)
platform28 = platform(60,4200,30,500,green)

platform29 = platform(4,4400,30,120,red)
platform30 = platform(180,4400,30,500,green)

platform31 = platform(4,4600,30,120,red) 
platform32 = platform(190,4600,30,400,red)
platform33 = platform(4,4800,30,440,red)
platform34 = platform(60,5000,30,500,red)
platform35 = platform(4,5200,30,320,red)
platform36 = platform(380,5200,30,400,red)
platform37 = platform(4,5400,30,150,red)
platform38 = platform(200,5400,30,400,green)
platform39 = platform(60,5600,30,500,red)
platform40 = platform(4,5800,30,250,red)
platform41 = platform(310,5800,30,350,red)
platform42 = platform(60,6000,30,500,red)
platform43 = platform(4,6200,30,300,red)
platform44 = platform(360,6200,30,200,red)
platform45 = platform(4,6400,30,440,green)
platform46 = platform(70,6600,30,480,red)
platform47 = platform(4,6800,30,440,red)
platform48 = platform(60,7000,30,500,red)
platform49 = platform(4,7200,30,50,red)
platform50 = platform(110,7200,30,400,red)
platform51 = platform(4,7400,30,300,red)
platform52 = platform(360,7400,30,300,red)
platform53 = platform(4,7600,30,60,red)
platform54 = platform(130,7600,30,500,red) 
platform55 = platform(4,7800,30,440,red)
platform56 = platform(4,8000,30,10,red)
platform57 = platform(70,8000,30,480,green)
platform58 = platform(60,8200,30,500,red)




platform59 = platform(4,8400,30,30,red)
platform60 = platform(90,8400,30,480,red)

platform61 = platform(4,8600,30,250,red)
platform62 = platform(310,8600,30,400,red)
platform63 = platform(4,8800,30,300,red)
platform64 = platform(360,8800,30,450,red)
platform65 = platform(4,9000,30,100,red)
platform66 = platform(160,9000,30,500,red)
platform67 = platform(4,9200,30,90,red)
platform68 = platform(150,9200,30,500,red)
platform69 = platform(4,9400,30,210,red)
platform70 = platform(270,9400,30,450,red)
platform71 = platform(4,9600,30,440,red)
platform72 = platform(60,9800,30,500,red)
platform73 = platform(4,10000,30,120,red)
platform74 = platform(190,10000,30,400,red)
platform75 = platform(4,10200,30,10,red)
platform76 = platform(70,10200,30,500,red)
platform77 = platform(4,10400,30,440,red)
platform78 = platform(60,10600,30,500,red)
platform79 = platform(4,10800,30,50,red)
platform80 = platform(110,10800,30,400,red)
platform81 = platform(4,11000,30,300,red)
platform82 = platform(360,11000,30,300,red)
platform83 = platform(4,11200,30,440,red)
platform84 = platform(60,11400,30,500,red)
platform85 = platform(4,11600,30,440,red)
platform86 = platform(4,11800,30,30,red)
platform87 = platform(90,11800,30,500,red)
platform88 = platform(60,12000,30,500,red)

platform89 = platform(4,12200,30,40,red)
platform90 = platform(100,12200,30,500,red)

platform91 = platform(4,12400,30,300,red)
platform92 = platform(360,12400,30,300,red)
platform93 = platform(70,12600,30,480,red)
platform94 = platform(4,12800,30,120,red)
platform95 = platform(190,12800,30,400,red)
platform96 = platform(4,13000,30,440,red)
platform97 = platform(60,13200,30,500,red)
platform98 = platform(4,13400,30,440,red)
platform99 = platform(4,13600,30,250,red)
platform100 = platform(310,13600,30,400,red) 
platform101 = platform(4,13800,30,30,red)
platform102 = platform(90,13800,30,480,red)
platform103 = platform(4,14000,30,440,red)
platform104 = platform(4,14200,30,50,red)
platform105 = platform(110,14200,30,400,red)
platform106 = platform(4,14400,30,440,red)
platform107 = platform(4,14600,30,340,red)
platform108 = platform(400,14600,30,500,red)
platform109 = platform(4,14800,30,60,red)
platform110 = platform(130,14800,30,500,red)
platform111 = platform(4,15000,30,440,red)
platform112 = platform(60,15200,30,480,red)
platform113 = platform(4,15400,30,40,red)
platform114 = platform(100,15400,30,500,red)
platform115 = platform(4,15600,30,30,red)
platform116 = platform(90,15600,30,480,red)
platform117 = platform(4,15800,30,170,red)
platform118 = platform(230,15800,30,480,red)
#walls
platform119 = platform(0,-10,30000,10,red)
platform120 = platform(490,-10,30000,10,red)


#LIST

items = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11,item12,item13,item14,item15,item16,item17,item18,item19,item20,item21,item22,item23,item24,item25,item26,item27,item28,item29,item30,item31,item32,item33,item34,item35,item36,item37,item38,item39,item40,item41,item42,item43,item44,item45,item46,item47,item48,item49,item50,item51,item52,item53,item54,item55,item56,item57,item58,item59,item60,item61,item62,item63,item64,item65,item66,item67,item68,item69,item70,item71,item72,item73,item74,item75,item76,item77,item78,item79,item80,item81,item82,item83,item84,item85,item86,item87,item88,item89,item90,item91,item92,item93,item94,item95,item96,item97,item98,item99,item100,item101,item102,item103,item104,item105,item106,item107,item108,item109,item110,item111,item112,item113,item114,item115,item116,item117,item118,item119,item120,item121,item122,item123,item124,item125,item126,item127,item128,item129,item130,item131,item132,item133,item134,item135,item136,item137,item138,item139,item140,item141,item142,item143,item144,item145,item146,item147,item148,item149,item150,item151,item152,item153,item154,item155,item156,item157,item158,item159,item160,item161,item162,item163,item164,item165,item166,item167,item168,item169,item170,item171,item172,item173,item174,item175,item176,item177,item178,item179,item180,item181,item182,item183,item184,item185,item186,item187,item188,item189,item190,item191,item192]


platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3,platform4,platform5,platform6,platform7,platform8,platform9,platform10,platform11,platform12,platform13,platform14,platform15,platform16,platform17,platform18,platform19,platform20,platform21,platform22,platform23,platform24,platform25,platform26,platform27,platform28,platform29,platform30,platform31,platform32,platform33,platform34,platform35,platform36,platform37,platform38,platform39,platform40,platform41,platform42,platform43,platform44,platform45,platform46,platform47,platform48,platform49,platform50,platform51,platform52,platform53,platform54,platform55,platform56,platform57,platform58,platform59,platform60,platform61,platform62,platform63,platform64,platform65,platform66,platform67,platform68,platform69,platform70,platform71,platform72,platform73,platform74,platform75,platform76,platform77,platform78,platform79,platform80,platform81,platform82,platform83,platform84,platform85,platform86,platform87,platform88,platform89,platform90,platform91,platform92,platform93,platform94,platform95,platform96,platform97,platform98,platform99,platform100,platform101,platform102,platform103,platform104,platform105,platform106,platform107,platform108,platform109,platform110,platform111,platform112,platform113,platform114,platform115,platform116,platform117,platform118]

fast = [item15,item35,item55,item70,item90,item130]

fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pause = False



black = (0,0,0)
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',25)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    game_loop()
    time.sleep(2)


    
    

def crash():
    message_display('You Crashed')


        

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False
    
def paused():

    window.fill(white)
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
    window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                
        #gameDisplay.fill(white)
        

        button("Can Run",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,unpause)
        button("Sit",300,350,100,50,red,darkred,quitgame)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


        
    
def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',95)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Lava Run", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((500/2),(500/2))
        window.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("Run!",100,350,100,50,green,darkgreen,game_loop)
        button("Sit!",300,350,100,50,red,darkred,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

        bg = pygame.image.load("Sky2.jpg")
        window.blit(bg,(0,0))
     
############################################

def game_loop():
    global pause

    
    #window
    def redrawwindow():
        window.fill((0,0,0))    

        #draw plyer
        player1.draw()
        platform119.draw()
        platform120.draw()
        for platform in platforms:
            platform.draw()

        # the score draw it on the screen
        window.blit(text,textRect)

        for item in items:
            item.draw()

            
    font  = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",30)
    score = 0
    text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((100,40))


    


                    
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(fps)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False


        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform5.rect):
            crash()
        
              

        
        if player1.rect.colliderect(platform119) and player1.rect.colliderect(platform120):
            player1.x = 40

    #going down

            # this makes things go down
        if player1.x < 600:
            for platform in platforms:
                platform.y -= 5

            for item in items:
                item.y -= 5

        if player1.y < -60:
            game_intro()

        for item in fast:
            if player1.rect.colliderect(item.rect):
                player1.speed +=1
                platform.y -= 5
                item.y -= 5

        

                
                
        if player1.y >450:
            player1.y -= player1.fall
            platform119.y -= player1.fall
            platform120.y -= player1.fall

            for platform in platforms:
                platform.y -= player1.fall
            

            for item in items:
                item.y -= player1.fall


         # coin collisions
        for item in items:
            for one in range(len(items)-1,-1,-1):
                if player1.rect.colliderect(items[one].rect):
                    del items[one]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render("Coins = "+str(score),True,(255,255,255))
                    textRect.center = ((100,40))

        
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]and player1.x > player1.speed:
            player1.x -= player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_d]and player1.x <500 - player1.height - player1.speed:
            player1.x += player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_p]:
            pause = True
            paused()

        if keys[pygame.K_w]and player1.y > player1.speed:
            player1.y -= player1.speed

        if keys[pygame.K_s]and player1.y <500 - player1.width - player1.speed:
            player1.y += player1.speed



        if not player1.isJump:
            player1.y += player1.fall
            player1.fall += 1
            player1.isJump = False


            collide = False
            # this part lets you jump on platform
            for platform in platforms:
                if player1.rect.colliderect(platform.rect):
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.y = platform.rect.top - player1.height + 1
                    if player1.rect.right > platform.rect.left and player1.rect.left < platform.rect.left - player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.left - player1.width
                    if player1.rect.left < platform.rect.right and player1.rect.right > platform.rect.right + player1.width:
                        player1.x = platform.rect.right
                              

                if player1.rect.bottom >= 500:
                    collide = True
                    player1.isJump = False
                    player1.JumpCount = 7
                    player1.y = 500 - player1.height

            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    player1.isJump = True
                player1.fall = 0


        else:
            if player1.JumpCount >= 0:
                player1.y -= (player1.JumpCount*abs(player1.JumpCount))*0.3
                player1.JumpCount -= 1
            else:
                player1.JumpCount = 7
                player1.isJump = False
        

        redrawwindow()
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    unpause
game_intro()
crash()
```

Comment: I am so sorry for so much variables, I was halfway doing it but I remembered the'r was an easier way but since I was half way I just kept on doing it.

Comment: The M in [mre] stands for minimal. It's unreasonable of you to expect people who are volunteering their time on SO to go through all of that code to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

In the game loop, recreate the player each time the game starts

```
def game_loop():
    global pause, player1
    player1 = player(255,-20,30,30,white)  # reset player at game start
```

When the game exits, just return back to the intro loop

```
if player1.y < -60:
    return  # go back to intro loop
    # game_intro()
```

You will also need to reset all the platforms when the game restarts.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jeiXenb9 I am still having the problem

Comment: The division returns a float. Use `500//2` instead.